# Passing JSON Objects from JAVA to JS

Tags: java, javascript, json

a java funxtion returns me an array of JSON Objects. 
there is a separate JS Code where I need this JSON Object.
I am beginner and have no clue how to do this.
I need to pass this JSON Object from java code to js code.
Kindly suggest me how should I proceed.

Comment: "I  have a java code". Show it to us.

Comment: the code cant be shared as my profs have asked me to keep it confidential. I am just supposed to take the json object generated from my prof's java code and use in my js file

Comment: So show us what you have tried to serialize a List of Objects to a JSON String.

Comment: Beginners writing confidential code? Sounds ridiculous…

Comment: You guys dont realize how difficult it is for beginners. even u were a beginner once.  Thanks to ravindranath who gave the reply instead of making fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Google's GSON library.

Input your professors JSON into GSON, get the java string representation, write it to a .js file. Just append "var json=" and save it in somefile.js. Now you can read that variable "json" in javascript.